# fwrite function not able to find directory other than local server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter with php. I am trying to write image in my file structure(Ubuntu file structure). This image is coming from url. My code to write image is

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
                $filename = "myImage.jpg";
                $filepath = "/opt/lampp/htdocs/affiliatedSystem/assets/file/".$filename;
                //Store in the filesystem.
                $fp = fopen($filepath , "w");
                fwrite($fp, $content);
                fclose($fp);
```

This code works perfectly fine on localhost but when I uploaded project on server its giving error like this

> *Message:  fopen(/opt/lampp/htdocs/affiliatedSystem/assets/file/myImage.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory* I also gave file
>   permission to folder 777 on server.

So, How can I write image on server?

Comment: did you check ownership of the folder? Like ubuntu : www-data or ubuntu : ubuntu?

Comment: what are you doing..opening an image in write mode? also writing content on it??

Comment: myImage is constant? why $filepath is fixed?

Comment: I want to save image in my file structure from url by coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I get the answer, I am using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] function at the starting of url like this`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/affiliatedsystem/assets/file/".$filename;`
and it gives me right url of my server and I am able to write file in my directory on server.

Answer (score 0):

(i can't add a comment, so i write in the answer. But is it the solution?).

I had the same problem on Fedora Linux. The owner of the folder was me and no apache. Try to change the owner folder with your user apache (if you use apache).

First, active httpd_unified :

> setsebool -P httpd_unified on

Second, give right to user apache :

> chown yourApacheUser:yourApacheGroup /var/www/..../yourDirectory

Comment: And what return file_exists("/opt/lampp/htdocs/affiliatedSystem/assets/file") ? If false, your path is bad OR the directory doesn't exsits. If true, chexk the owner directory.